# How to fix remote Matlab display resolution when using ssh -X?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, ssh, display, screen-resolution

I have a Desktop computer (Ubuntu 18.10) which I use for my heavy computations. When not at the office, I use my Macbook (Late 2012, retina display).
I would like to run Matlab remotely from Desktop Ubuntu, onto my MacOSX using `ssh -X`.

When I do so, Matlab opens using OpenGL rendering. I would like to know if there is a way to impose a rendering that fits my screen resolution (in my case Retina display resolution (2560-by-1600)?

BONUS question: if possible doing so without permanently changing the resolution in which Matlab is displayed on my Ubuntu computer (and for which I use the hardware rendering of my NVidia GPU and not OpenGL).